# A simpler method to show $x^6+x^3+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The original is show that  $x^6+x^3+1$ cannot be written as a product of
two polynomials of integer coefficients and positive degrees.(I think it is equivalent to show that the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]$.)

I tried the $(x^3+ax^2+bx+ c)(x^3+dx^2+ex+ f)$ and $(x^2+ax+b)(x^4+cx^3+dx^2+ ex+f)$ forms and get the contrary（I have already get the result）.The calculation seems a bit large.

Is there any simpler methond for this question.Thanks.

Comment: do you know anything about cyclotomic polynomials? Or primitive roots of unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x=y+1$, so we have:

$$f(x)=x^6+x^3+1=y^6+6y^5+15y^4+21y^3+18y^2+9y+3=g(y)$$

Apply Eisenstein's criterion to $g(y)$ with $p=3$ to see that $g(y)$ is irreducible.  Now, any factorization of $f(x)$ into two non-constant polynomials would give such a factorization of $g(y)$, but no such exists.

Comment: +1; I was just about to give this answer.  In general, trying simple $y=x\pm k$ substitutions for small $k$ and then checking Eisenstein's criterion is a good one.  In this case in particular, by the binomial theorem you should know that the coefficients of $y^n$ in $(y+1)^6$ will be divisible by three if $n$ isn't a multiple of three, and similarly for $(y+1)^3$, and since the constant terms of from the three terms $(y+1)^6$, $(y+1)^3$ and $1$ will sum to $3$ it's a natural choice.